# Prod environment works, dev fails

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony

History:
Original title:

> Access denied...user is not fully authenticated; login
>   IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY

A fully functional 2.8.8 site was rebuilt on a fresh 3.1.2 installation.  Once Symfony was installed, `composer.json` was modified to include the dependencies from the 2.8 site.  Installation was successful.  Dev environment behaves as described below.  In an effort to gain additional handles on the problem, the prod environment was reviewed.  It revealed some deprecations that were not revealed in the 2.8 phpunit testing.  Once those were cleared the 3.1 prod environment behaved as the 2.8 prod environment.  The conclusion is that there is some difference between 2.8 and 3.1 dev environments that causes the problem.  Of course, I may have shot myself in the foot somewhere along the way.

Original question:

In a fresh 3.1 installation w/ FOSUserBundle, `/login`, `/` routes result in a loop with dev log entries:

Edit: The entire site is to be secured.  The access_control directive `{ path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }` is NOT a mistake.  The site works just fine in Symfony 2.8.8.

Edit #2: It turns out the prod environment behaves properly.  Dev does not.  `config_dev.yml` and `routing_dev.yml` are the default ymls for 3.1.

```
request.INFO: Matched route "{route}". {"route":"fos_user_security_login" ...
security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token....
security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point
security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point....
```

Chrome says:

> redirected you too many times

Firewall change required?

security.yml (basic, from [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html):, with modification)

```
security:
    encoders:
      FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
        algorithm: md5
        ignore_case: true
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations: 1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Have you registered the user yet via /register url?

Comment: I get the above when trying to get to the site as an anonymous user, thus never registered.  The expectation is that as an anonymous user I will then be required to login.  This is what happens in the application branch built in Symfony 2.8.8.

Comment: I should add: with the exact same `security.yml`.

Comment: what if you remove line `pattern: ^/` from config?

Comment: - { path: ^/*, role: ROLE_USER }

Comment: Interesting ideas (removing pattern, adding wildcard), but no change in site behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than an answer, I post this so as to retain the above discussion showing what does not resolve the issue.  In an effort to reproduce the problem I started a second effort to migrate the working 2.8 application into 3.1.  This time I was successful; I cannot identify what caused the difficulty presented above.

Please consider the question withdrawn.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you secured your login_check route - hence when the user submit the login forms, the request is caught and he is redirected to another login form.

Try adding this rule:

```
access_control:
    # ...
    - { path: ^/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: No change in behavior with this addition